# Swift Type Variable for conditional optional unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to set a type variable and then use it to conditionally unwrap an optional. Here is an example:

```
func testInt() {
    var test:Int? = 15

    let intType = Int.self

    if let testInt = test as? intType {
        print("is a int")
    } else {
        print("not a int")
    }
}
```

In the example above I get an error of `'intType' is not a type`.

Is this even possible to do?

I have tried `.Type` as well and I get the same error.

Edit****

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.  The above example was only meant to be a simple example of storing a type in a variable.  I understand that there are other ways to accomplish what the function above does...

```
class TableCell0: UITableViewCell {}
class TableCell1: UITableViewCell {}

enum SectionInfo: Int {
    case section0 = 0, section1

    var cellIdentifier: String {
        let identifiers = ["Section0Cell", "Section1Cell"]
        return identifiers[self.rawValue]
    }

    var cellType: UITableViewCell.Type {
        let types:[UITableViewCell.Type] = [TableCell0.self, TableCell1.self]
        return types[self.rawValue]
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let sectionInfo = SectionInfo(rawValue: indexPath.section) else {
        fatalError("Unexpected section passed from tableView")
    }

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(sectionInfo.cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? sectionInfo.cellType else {
        fatalError("unexpected cell dequeued from tableView")
    }
    return cell
}
```

This should create the correct type of cell I want

Comment: If your var test it is an optional Int you should use `guard` or `if let ` to unwrap your value. `if let test = test { ... // test it is not nil and has a value  }`

Comment: I understand I could use guard or if let and use an explicit type i.e. as? Int  But my question is if I store the type in a variable why can't I use that variable as the type in the downcast.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. Use `dynamicType` to compare it, rather than conditionally unwrapping the optional.

```
func testInt() {
    var test:Int = 15
    let intType = Int.self

    if test.dynamicType == intType {
        print("is a int")
    } else {
        print("not a int")
    }
}
```

At least that would work for your Integer example, not sure if it will work for your UITableViewCell example or not.

Answer (score 0):

Int Example,

```
 var myValue: Int = 1
 if let test = myValue as? Int {
     print("IS INT") // hits here
 } else {
     print("NOT INT")
 }
```

Non-Int Example,

```
 var myValue: Float = 1.1
 if let test = myValue as? Int {
     print("IS INT")
 } else {
     print("NOT INT") // hits here
 }
```

moot point I suppose since the compiler will let you know that you already know the type anyway. AKA "always fails" or "always succeeds"

Comment: I know how to do it like this but my question is about storing the type in a variable and using that to downcast.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you are trying to do, But if you want to check if the variable is of type **int**, You can use **is**

```
func testInt() {
    let test:Int? = 15

    // let intType = Int.self <-----comment this out. you dont need it

    if test! is Int {        //i'm force unwrapping "test!" cause you declared it as optional        
        print("is a int")
    } else {
        print("not a int")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func test<T>(type: T.Type) {
    let test:Int? = 15


    if let _ = test as? T {
        print("is a int")
    } else {
        print("not a int")
    }
}

test(Int)    // is a int
test(Double) // not a int
```

or ...

```
func test<T>(type: T.Type, what: Any) {

    if let w = what as? T {
        print(w, "is a \(T.Type.self)")
    } else {
        print(what, "not a \(T.Type.self)")
    }
}

test(Int.self, what: 1)
test(Double.self, what: 1)
test(Double.self, what: 2.2)

/*
1 is a Int.Type
1 not a Double.Type
2.2 is a Double.Type
*/
```

based on your notes, you can use generic approach and still use variable to 'save' your type // test() from first example

```
let t1 = Int.self
let t2 = Double.self
test(t1)    // is a int
test(t2)    // not a int
```

t1 and t2 are both constant, t1 has type Int.Type.Type, t2 has type Double.Type.Type. You can not cast as? t1 or as? t2.

Comment: This is using the generic as the type for the downcast I understand how to do this as well.  I am looking to see if it is possible to store a type in a variable and use that variable as the type in the downcast

Comment: Please see my edit above for a better example of what I would like to do.